# Unexpected Token

Tags: html, angularjs

Estou fazendo uma aplicação com angularjs e o erro "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" fica disparando

Segue o código js

```
angular.module('alurapic').controller('FotoController', function ($scope) {
$scope.foto = {}

$scope.submeter = function () {
    console.log($scope.foto)
}
})
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" ng-app="alurapic" class="ng-scope">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Alurapic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/efeitos.css">
</head>
 <body>
    <div class="container">
        <ng-view>

        </ng-view>
    </div> <!-- fim container -->
    <script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/fotos-controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives/minhas-diretivas.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/controllers/foto-controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consegues reproduzir esse erro num jsFiddle ou aqui no widget do SOpt?

Comment: faltou os colchetes em angular.module('alurapic', []), porém esse erro é relacionado a outra coisa creio eu